# Character table of $G=\langle x,y \mid x^4=y^3=1,yx=xy^2\rangle$

Tags: representation-theory, characters, group-presentation

I have a group $G$ with the following presentation $G=\langle x,y \mid x^4=y^3=1,yx=xy^2\rangle$. I know its conjugacy classes and I have to compute the character table :

Now since $y$ and $y^2$ are in the same conjugacy class, I have $\lambda_i(y)=\lambda_i(y)^2$ so $\lambda_i(y)=1$ or $\lambda_i(y)=0$ but since $y^3=1 \lambda_i^3(y)=1$ so we cannot have $\lambda_i(y)=0$. Then I am stuck. I feel I have to use the fact that $x^2$ is in the center.

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & \{1\} & \{x^2\} & \{x,xy,xy^2\} & \{y,y^2\}  & \{x^3,x^3y\} & \{x^3,y^3\}\\
 \text{Triv}& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1\\
\lambda_1&1&&&1&&\\
\lambda_2&1&&&1&&\\
\lambda_3&1&&&1&&\\
\chi_1&2&&&&&\\
\chi_2&2&&&&&
\end{array}

Comment: You have started to calculate before you've said all you can about the group - or so it seems to me. Clearly $\langle y\rangle$ is normal, so the first thing to do is explore the characters of the quotient ... [end of hint]

Comment: Thank you. I found $G/\langle y \rangle \cong C_4$ and this helped me to complete the table!